# How to replicate jobs between nodes with SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2022, contained-database

I created a contained availability group but I don't know why the jobs are not synchronized between the nodes.
What could be the problem? Shouldn't it do it automatically?

---

In response to the answer I have performed the following:

I'm connected on the server that we are now using as Primary (xxxxx) and I've created a test job there.

The sync for the dbs is working perfectly, but it is not working for logins and jobs.

Comment: Please update the question to show that you've run through the items I've already given. The latest updates you've posted do not add anything as it stands.

Answer (score 6):

> Shouldn't it do it automatically?

Yes, it should.

> What could be the problem?

Most likely you're doing one of the following:

1. Connecting to the physical master when creating the job, which means it won't be created in the logical master which is needed to sync the logins and jobs.
2. Connecting to the logical master to create the job but when checking to see if it sync'd properly connected to the physical master on the secondary.
3. Synchronization health is problematic, as in it's not in a synchronizing or synchronized state.

You'll needed to double check these items.

Answer (score -3):

not possible to do. logins and agent jobs are instance level are not covered by Availability groups.

Comment: [What is a contained availability group?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/contained-availability-groups-overview)